# "подходит два" или "подходят два"

Tags: числительные, единственное-множественное-число

> К бару подходят два человека.

Здесь все правильно и по канонам.

> К бару подходит два человека.

Почему нельзя сказать в единственном числе или можно? (и в чем тогда смысловая разница).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: **К бару подходят два человека.**

Согласование во мн. числе выбрано  по семантическому принципу: здесь два действующих лица, **действие активное, совершается каждым лицом отдельно.**

Сравнить: *У бара **находилось** несколько человек* (речь идет о группе людей, действие пассивное).

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_02

1. Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совместное действие, форма множественного числа – на раздельное совершение действия. Ср.: Пять солдат отправилось в разведку (группой). – Пять солдат отправились в разведку (каждый с самостоятельным заданием); К началу экзамена явилось десять студентов. – Десять студентов окончили институт с отличием.

Comment: Так вы сами говорите что можно указать на совместное действие. К бару подходит пара человек (два человека). Разве это не будет грамматически правильно?

Comment: Еще можно поменять значение слова подходят с действия на состояние. К примеру: два ключа подходит к этой замочной скважине. Уж здесь не придраться: подходить тут состояние, а не действие. Тогда все ОК?

Comment: Если определять на слух, то "К бару подходит два человека" будет некорректным, так не говорят. Почему? В современном языке согласование по смыслу считается основным: два действующих предмета, значит,  мн. число. Объяснять надо скорее согласование в ед. числе. И на первом месте - активность или пассивность действия, обозначенного глаголом.  Идти - это активное действие каждого, мы так это представляем, поэтому вариант с ед. числом определяем как неверный. Здесь даже просматривается другое значение глагола  - быть годным (что-то вроде бару подходит (нужно) два человека на эту должность.

Answer (score 2):

В единственном числе можно, но только в специальном контексте, когда требуется акцент на *количестве* людей, а не на конкретных индивидах (условно говоря, "сколько их подходит" а не "вон те двое").

> Мы долго выбирали новое место для бара: нас больше не устраивало, что на
>   этой безлюдной улице за весь вечер **к бару подходит два человека**.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто — смотрим на окончание:
Если два человек**а**/ключ**а** — то подход**я**т. || Окончание *-а*.
Если [группа] человек/ключ**ей** — то подход**и**т.

Comment: В модельных примерах окончания одинаковы (солдат), а число глаголов(отправилось/отправились) разное. Так что смотреть на окончания существительного не универсальный метод:

Пять солдат отправилось в разведку (группой). – Пять солдат отправились в разведку (каждый с самостоятельным заданием).

Лучше ориентироваться на признак состояние/действие глагола. Но тогда два ключа подходит, а не подходят.

Comment: А окончания больше про цифру 2, вопрос же про неё. *Два ключа нам подходит.* Но: *Два ключа подходят к замку (каждый подходит по отдельности).*